# Calling SubViewController issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

In iOS Application when some link pressed, I am calling a view from my current RootViewController like:

```
SubViewController *view = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithItem:itemID];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: view animated: YES];
```

But for some reason view is not getting called and instead I get animation effect on top of navigation bar but view itself stay the same.

What could be the problem? What should I change to make it work?

Comment: What is initWithItem:? Is that your own method? If so, you should post the code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have gone wrong with the code.You are not Loading the view

```
SubViewController *view=[[SubViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nib file for that viewcontroller you need to use this code..

```
YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Or If you dont have nib file then simply use this code

```
YourViewController *obj = [[YourViewController alloc]ini];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in new x-code 4.5,  All i had to do was uncheck the option of "Use-Autolayout" in interface builder in view layout.